# Why didn't Kazuya use his freezing ability against Chiffon?

Tags: freezing

On the last two episodes of *Freezing Vibration* (2nd season of *Freezing*), we could see Kazuya, Rana, and Satellizer fighting Chevalier's Pandora and Student Council President Chiffon Fairchild.

In this fight, although set as 2 against 1, Satellizer and Rana were badly wounded and beaten.

I was wondering, Kazuya was there and he has this powerful Freezing field he can generate on his own. So why did Kazuya not use his freezing ability against Chiffon?

Even though fighting against a "True" Pandora, two Pandoras working together with activated stigmata and a very powerful Freezing can mean a lot.

He used it in other episodes when he was fighting beside Satellizer against other tough pandoras. So why didn't he use it against Chiffon?

Comment: If I remember it correctly, Kazuya don't have a complete control over his ability, thus sometimes wouldn't be able to use it. Other than that, it is because if he used it, fans wouldn't be able to see Satellizer and Rana *beaten up* (you know what I mean) i.e. fan service.

Comment: hahaha  . . .  that little guy can`t do anything againts Chiffon-sama, The Smiling Monster :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Kazuya doesn't know how to control his powers. This can be seen every time he uses them. It is always in the last second and only if somebody is in danger, especially Bridgette.

In this fight, he is unable to use it, because he does not want to hurt Chiffon. Also he sees that Rana and Bridgette have no chance of winning any way. Rana's arms were ripped off in a second and after she transformed and beat up Chiffon, Chiffon just stands up as if nothing happened.

> Also, Kazuya's powers are needed a bit later and he tends to overexert himself. So it would be impossible to solve the problems which arise later.